# Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NOT_PAID

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

[image]

Trying to publish an Android release, I receive this error: Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NOT_PAID;
Is there anyone who had this error before in the google play console;

Comment: There should be something in "inbox" section. Can you check?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue? Having issues with the same...